# Standard Java Classes for FTP operations

Tags: java, ftp

Can I use standard Java Classes for FTP operations (upload, download, delete, list...) ? 
Because, I found a good FTP client librabry [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/), but my manager wants to write her own based off the standard classes.

How can I get my manager to allow us to use the package above, and if she does not buy into the use of this library, what pitfalls will we likely encounter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why would your manager not want to use a proven piece of software and replace it with something that you'd have to write, test, and maintain?  Your boss is an idiot - use the Apache FTP client and move on.  You have more interesting business problems to solve.

Answer (score 2):

There are FTP classes in the JDK, see sun.net.FtpClient.

Comment: Be careful using the sun classes; just because they are in the JDK does not mean that they are "standard Java classes." These classes are specific to the Sun/Oracle JRE and may not be available everywhere your application is deployed. It's a great suggestion and I'm sure the classes work great, just know that you are still working with non-standard code here.

Answer (score -1):

The Apache Commons classes are standard classes. They are widely spread and come with thorough testing and documentation. They do offer a much better handling with ftp-handled file transfer than the JDK classes.